# Find if item in collection with value exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

First of all, here is my very simple component :

```
var RenewedLoanModal = new Vue ({
      el: '#myModal',
      data:
        {
          responses: []
        }
      });
```

`responses` is filled up by an ajax call, it is an array of objects.
Here is the structure :

```
responses: [
    {error: 'foo', message: 'foo', id: 'foo', success: true},
    {error: 'bar', message: 'bar', id: 'bar', success: false},
    ...
]
```

I am trying to know if one of these object have a `success: false` but I didn't find anyway to check it.

Is there a way to iterate through the `responses` collection in a method, not in the view rendering ? Or maybe a `v-if` test ?

Comment: yes, there are many ways. simplest will be to make a computed property which does the checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to check if an item exists in a collection by its properties.

### Plain Javascript

The first thing you could do using only plain javascript is the following:

```
var success = false
for (var i = 0; i < responses.lenth; i++) {
  if (responses[i].success === true) success = true
}
```

### ECMAScript 6

You can do it in ES6 like this:

```
var success = responses.reduce((prev, cur) => prev || cur.success, false)
```

### Functional programming

Another more declarative way is by using the [Ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/) library:

```
// if 'any' of the elements satisfy the predicate
var success = R.any(response => response.success === true)(responses)
// or more briefly
var success = R.any(response => response.success)(responses)
```

---

## Hooking it up in Vue.js

After you create say, a computed property with the above return result, you can hook it up to a `v-if` or a `v-show` if you want to conditionally display something.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would use:

`data: {
  hadError: false,
  responses: []
}`

and let the addResponse(data, resp) do the job:

`if(resp.success === false) data.hadError = true;
data.responses.push(resp);`

otherwise:

`for(i=0; i<responses.length; i++) {
  if(response[i].success === false)
    .....
}`